# Getting no data when I access the model from the controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having a problem accessing the model from the controller correctly I believe because I have a dropdownlist in my code which changes the currency for the user's total and I have separate dropdownlists that when chosen change the user's current total based on their choices. I'm able to get the total to populate correctly based on what options they choose but if I try to change the currency it always shows the `model.Price` as 0 which is obviously a mistake. I'm still new to MVC but I read up on it and I thought I was accessing the `model.Price` correctly.

Here's my model code

```
public class WritingAppModel
{
    // ... other existing properties

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is Required.")]
    [Range(0.01, 10000.00, ErrorMessage = "Your quote is not complete because you haven't completed all of the steps.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
WritingAppModel model = new WritingAppModel();

public JsonResult getNewPrice(modelData dropdownValues)
{
    // check for urgency first since that is the base price
    if (dropdownValues.urgency != null)
    {
        currentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dropdownValues.urgency);

        if (dropdownValues.documentType != null)
        {
            currentPrice = currentPrice + Convert.ToDecimal(dropdownValues.documentType);

            if (dropdownValues.numberOfPages != null)
            {
                currentPrice = currentPrice * Convert.ToInt16(dropdownValues.numberOfPages);
            }
        }
    }

    model.Price = currentPrice;
    // do something with value and return a decimal
    return Json(new { currentPrice = model.Price.ToString("C") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public decimal changeCurrency(string newCurrency)
{
    // if this is the first time then make sure current currency is set to dollar
    if (defaultCurrency == null)
    {
        defaultCurrency = "USD";
    }

    // see if new currency is different
    if ((newCurrency != defaultCurrency) && (model.Price > 0))
    {
        return convertCurrency(currentPrice, newCurrency);
    }
    else
    {
        // if nothing changes
        return currentPrice;
    }
}

public decimal convertCurrency(decimal amount, string toCurrency)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    decimal rate = 0;
    string url = String.Format("https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id={0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OpenExchangeRate_AppID"]);

    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(url)))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Currency>(json);

        if (toCurrency == "EUR")
        {
            rate = items.rates.EUR * amount;
        }
        if (toCurrency == "GBP")
        {
            rate = items.rates.GBP * amount;
        }
    }

    return Math.Round(rate, 2);
}
```

Ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#currencyList').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/changeCurrency?newCurrency=" + this.value,
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#priceLabel').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Currency, (SelectList)ViewBag.currency, null, new { id = "currencyList" })
<h2 id="priceLabel">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
</h2>
```

Comment: Cant follow this. Is `getNewPrice` relevant? You don't seem to be calling it anywhere. `changeCurrency` should return a JsonResult (as you did for `getNewPrice`. `changeCurrency` is referencing `defaultCurrency` but that's not initialized anywhere and then it references `model.Price` which is a new instance of the model so I assume the value of `model.Price` is always zero (unless you have set a default value in its constructor)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I only included it to show how I was changing the price based on their selection and that there was a price saved to the model but I'm trying to access the same data with the changecurrency function and it is always zero

Comment: But your not sending the price from the view to the controller. All you are doing is initializing an new instance of your model and formatting its price (which has a value of zero)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So is there any way for ajax to access the model data without passing it? And thank you for helping me figure this out. The answer just wasn't coming to me

Comment: I've added some comments to ekads answer that may help resolve your issue, but I'm not entirely sure what your trying to do. Your `getNewPrice` really should be sending both an unformatted decimal value (which you then pass back to the `changeCurrency` method) and a formatted currency value which you use to update the display.

Comment: I agree with your assessment

Comment: The `getNewPrice` method seems unnecessary. You could just do all this on the client using javascript to add/multiply the values and store the result in a variable. Then you would pass that variable and the culture to the `changeCurrency` method and return a formatted value (based on the culture) as a JsonResult to update your display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this block of code in `changeCurrency` method

```
if ((newCurrency != defaultCurrency) && (model.Price > 0))
{
    return convertCurrency(currentPrice, newCurrency);
}
```

`model.Price` will always be 0 since you call `changeCurrency` method by ajax, not by submitting the form. You need to pass current unformatted price from the view to `changeCurrency` method and replace `model.Price` in the above block to the decimal equivalent of the current price. Since the price can have different formats, you need to add a new `UnFormattedPrice` properties to hold the unformatted price

```
public class WritingAppModel
{
    // ... other existing properties

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is Required.")]
    [Range(0.01, 10000.00, ErrorMessage = "Your quote is not complete because you haven't completed all of the steps.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string UnFormattedPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Price.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

then add a hidden field to hold the unformatted price

```
<h2 id="priceLabel">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
</h2>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UnFormattedPrice)
```

`changeCurrency` method should have a new `price` parameter and return json that contains both formatted and unformatted price

```
public JsonResult changeCurrency(string newCurrency, string price)
{
    // if this is the first time then make sure current currency is set to dollar
    if (defaultCurrency == null)
    {
        defaultCurrency = "USD";
    }

    currentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(price);

    decimal newPrice = 0;
    // see if new currency is different
    if ((newCurrency != defaultCurrency) && (currentPrice > 0))
    {
        newPrice = convertCurrency(currentPrice, newCurrency);
    }
    else
    {
        // if nothing changes
        newPrice = currentPrice;
    }

    return Json(new { currentPrice = newPrice.ToString("C"), unformattedCurrentPrice = newPrice.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

then pass the value of `$('#UnFormattedPrice')` as the price parameter in your ajax call. When the ajax call is success, set the value of `<h2 id="priceLabel">` to the formatted price and set the value of `$('#UnFormattedPrice')` to the unformatted price.

```
$('#currencyList').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/changeCurrency?newCurrency=" + this.value + "&price=" + $('#UnFormattedPrice').val(),
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#priceLabel').html(result.currentPrice);
            $('#UnFormattedPrice').val(result.unformattedCurrentPrice);
        }
    });
});
```

You should do the similar thing with `getNewPrice` method and the related ajax call.

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal(price);` probably wont work if the the value of `price` is already a formatted currency string. Probably need to post the culture info of the current format as well?

Comment: Probably easiest to return both the formatted and unformatted values in the `getNewPrice` method, then the unformatted decimal can be cached on the client and its that value which gets sent to the `changeCurrency` method along with the format string.

Comment: I don't think `currentPrice = decimal.Parse(price, NumberStyles....)` is going to work either, since it parsing the value based on the current culture on the server, not the culture of the value which was initially passed to the client.

Comment: The regex wont work either, since some cultures use a dot as the decimal separator and others use a comma.

Comment: I was having trouble with that as well. I'm open to trying whatever you think will work

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)` will display a formatted value if the property has a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute. Then (I think) the `getNewPrice` method is updating the value based on some selections (again its a formatted currency value). At this point its using the server culture, but the `changeCurrency` then needs to take the formatted string (say `$100.00`) and convert that to another culture. If the `changeCurrency` is then called again, the string passed back is in another culture which might be `E100,00` so the regex would now return `$10000.00`

Comment: @ekad I edited my post to include the ajax query for the price change to make sure I have it correct. Am I able to ask you a question? I have one of the drop down lists that I want to save the dropdownlist text to the model instead of the value. I have been searching everywhere for how to do that and I can't seem to figure out how

Comment: @user3610374 I think it would be better if you ask a new question for that particular problem, it seems out of context of this question.

Comment: Ok sorry I just figured I would ask. Thank you again for helping me out